# Re-index SQLite do not understand how

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sqlite

This is my first time with SQLite and I am trying to reindex my SQLite DB, after deleted record, but always get the max nr of records in each 'id' row.

[image]

'id' row should be 1, 2, 3 etc.

[image]

When I have deleted a record I want to reindex the whole table so 'id' starts with 1 and ends with max records number.

I have been trying all kinds of things, googled a lot, but failed. Here is the code I use:

```
void ReIndexDB ()
{
    List<string> importedFiles = new List<string>();
    int recNr = 1;
    int id;

    OpenDB();
    dbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand();
    sqlQuery = "SELECT * from questions";
    dbcmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

    reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand();
        dbcmd2 = dbconn.CreateCommand();

        sqlQuery = "UPDATE questions SET id = '" + recNr + "'";
        recNr++;

        dbcmd2.CommandText = sqlQuery;                                              // sets dbcmd.CommandText to be equal to the insert statement created above
        dbcmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    txt_nrOfQuestions.text = recNr.ToString() + " questions in DB";

    reader.Close();
    dbconn.Close();
    reader = null;
    dbcmd.Dispose();
    dbcmd2.Dispose();
    dbcmd = null;
    dbconn = null;

    img_ConfirmationDelete1.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(630f, -15f);
    UIAccess(true);

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to renumber the Primary Key?  Usually databases will not allow the primary key to be changed.

Comment: You are missing `WHERE` in update command so you every time update each row...eventually end up with the highest recNr...

Comment: "UPDATE questions SET id = '" + recNr "' WHERE id = '" + reader["id"] '"; not sure about syntax but you get the point...

Comment: tx, see that now.

Comment: @PeterK please respond if that is the solution to post the actual answer...